# How to allow write permission to AppPoolIdentity user in IIS 10

Tags: windows, iis, web-deployment, windows-server-2016

I have a website hosted on IIS 10. The website has a feature to write files in a folder.  I have given write permission to IIS_IUSER, IUSER and USER groups on the wwwroot folder.However, I still see access denied exception. 
One workaround I do is allowing write permission to AppPoolIdentity user (the user with name name as my application name) on the website folder. However, this permission gets removed each time I do a web deploy.

Is there something I am missing? I have windows server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Web Deploy from Visual Studio, the publish will overwrite the ACLs on the server by clearing them to the inherited defaults of the parent.

To avoid update ACL each time when you publish your web application.

You could add below command in your PublishProfiles's pubxml.

```
 <IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>
```

Details publish profile as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>http://localhost:9825/</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>WebFormApplication</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>InProc</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName />
    <_SavePWD>False</_SavePWD>
     <IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>False</IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
            <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="WebFromIdentityTest.Models.ApplicationDbContext, WebFromIdentityTest" Origin="Configuration" />
          </Object>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```